# Gradient / rate of change problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Example: Let $f(x,y)=x^2+\cos{y}$. The rate of change at $f$ at $(1,0)$ in the direction of $<1,1>$ is:

A. $1$
B. $\sqrt{2}$
C. $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
D. $\pi$
E. $0$

I'm confused on how to start this. Am I supposed to find the gradient, plug in $(1,0)$ and take the dot product of this with $<1,1>$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [directional derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html), which is indeed as you say, except you have to dot with the *unit* vector in the direction of $(1,1)$, and $(1,1)$ has length $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is b
What u thought of doing is correct. But after finding the gradient take the dot product of the gradient with the unit vector along the direction of <1,1>